# Using docker to package a web app including fixed MySQL data

Tags: mysql, docker, large-data-volumes, database-dump

I have a website with very specific JS code associated with a large, unchanging, MySQL database. I want to be able to distribute the website plus database as a single package for others to be able to run locally, so I have been investigating doing this using docker. Note that I'm not using docker for *testing* the running app: merely for distributing it for others to look at.

By my understanding, docker images that run a populated MySQL database usually load it up from a `.sql` file after starting the DB. However, for my database contents, this results in an hour-long wait to populate the database, since the .sql dump is many gigabytes, and takes that long to load. Therefore I was thinking of loading the data into the running database once, keeping the db volume (`/var/lib/mysql`) local to the image, and creating a snapshot of the image using `docker commit` once the data has been loaded.

However, this approach seems to go against many standard docker recommendations: usually `docker commit` is frowned upon, and `/var/lib/mysql` is stored as a separate data-volume, not saved in the image itself. Nevertheless, my use-case seems different, as (a) the data in the database is not intended to change in the future (b) it takes a long time to load from a mysql dump and (c) the large data store (rather than just the js app code) is one of the main things that I actually want to include in the image.

So is my use-case a valid reason to break convention and use `docker commit` together with saving the MySQL files in the image itself rather than a separate data volume? Or is there an alternative, more standard way of distributing a fully working, fully-populated web app with a large fixed database store?

Comment: _“usually docker commit is frowned upon”_ The statement lacks substance; do you have anything to back it up?

Comment: Suggestion - Can't you use sqlite to hold static data?

Comment: Another approach could be to package a database dump in your docker image. You can restore this dump before starting your application.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @ashu. Here's a link talking about docker commit being not recommended (point 5) https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/24/10-things-to-avoid-in-docker-containers/ . Re sqlite - I suspect the access won't be fast enough for our needs. Re db dump in the image - if the dump is in .sql format it will take too long to load into the DB for sensible packaging as a distributed web app (see discussion in the question)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that instead of using `docker commit`, you can use multi-stage builds. In an early stage of the build, a `RUN` command can be used to populate the database (e.g. resulting in the DB files being created in `/var/lib/mysql`). If `/var/lib/mysql` is a data volume, then as the last stage of the build, the entire `/var/lib/mysql` directory can be copied to a permanent, non-data volume location, e.g. `/var/lib/mysql_permanent`, using e.g.

```
ENV MYSQL_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/mysql_permanent
# copy the DB files from the previous image
COPY --from=create_database "/var/lib/mysql" "${MYSQL_DATA_DIR}"
```

The final image will then be created with the correct underlying database files baked into the image. The last build stage then needs to run the `mysqld` process with a  mysqld.cnf file specifying `datadir=${MYSQL_DATA_DIR}`, to access the correct files. This then bypasses the need for `docker commit`, and does everything in the build stage.

Comment: Can you please share the entire multi-stage build code?

Comment: The build is at https://github.com/OneZoom/OZtree-docker/blob/main/Dockerfile